# How to set loop number of lottiefiles animation in android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, animation, lottie

I am facing a problem using Lottie files as an animation. I can not set loop number while after loading it is looping continuously but I want to set fixed loop number.

Activity XML

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/animation_view_1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />
```

Activity Java

```
animationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animationView.setAnimation(fileName);
        animationView.loop(true);
        animationView.playAnimation();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As         `animationView.loop(true);`
is deprecated.
In addition to Phan Van Linh asnwer,
Using .xml file

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        ...
        app:lottie_repeatCount="3"
        />
```

Using java you can use

```
animationView.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);// for Infinite loops
```

OR

```
animationView.setRepeatCount(3);// for 3 loops
```

Comment: The Above answers are perfect but there is one more easier way,
This is deprecated but it works for now

    `animationView.loop(true);`

Comment: yup, for the future purpose we must not use animationView.loop(true);

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        ...
        app:lottie_repeatCount="3"
        />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use jetpack compose:

1. Get lottie composition from resources:

```
// Get lottie composition
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.idea_anim))
```

2. Create state of animation for composition, to set number of iterations use `iterations = 3`, for infinity we use `iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever`:

```
// State of animation for composition
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition,
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
)
```

3. Create LottieAnimation composable:

```
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = { progress }
)
```

Full code:

```
@Composable
fun AnyScreen() {
    // Get lottie composition
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.idea_anim))

    // State of animation for composition
    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition = composition,
        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
    )

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        progress = { progress }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to do programatically there is method `setRepeatCount()`

```
animationView.setRepeatCount(count)
```

> /**
>      * Sets how many times the animation should be repeated. If the repeat
>      * count is 0, the animation is never repeated. If the repeat count is
>      * greater than 0 or {@link LottieDrawable#INFINITE}, the repeat mode will be taken
>      * into account. The repeat count is 0 by default.
>      *
>      * @param count the number of times the animation should be repeated
>      */
>
> `public void setRepeatCount(int count) {
>       lottieDrawable.setRepeatCount(count);
>     }`